# Default ssl_dhparam file used by nginx in RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, security, nginx, ssl

Where is the default dhparam file used by the nginx web server after a fresh install of CentOS 8?

Let's say I do a fresh install of nginx on CentOS 8:

```
yum install nginx
```

And I do not have any `ssl_dhparam` options set

```
[root@cent8 /]# grep -irl ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx
[root@cent8 /]#
```

What is the default dhparam file in-use by my web server? How was it generated? And how big is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default ssl\_dhparam file used by nginx in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673686/default-ssl-dhparam-file-used-by-nginx-in-debian)

Answer (score 0):

Not used by default, you need to generate it manually and specify the full path to it.