# Default ssl_dhparam file used by nginx

Tags: security, nginx, ssl

Where is the default dhparam file used by the nginx web server after a fresh install of Debian 11?

Let's say I do a fresh install of nginx on Debian 11:

```
apt install nginx
```

And I do not have any `ssl_dhparam` options set

```
[root@debian11 /]# grep -irl ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx
[root@debian11 /]#
```

What is the default dhparam file in-use by my web server? How was it generated? And how big is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_dhparam) for `ssl_dhparam`:

> By default no parameters are set, and therefore DHE ciphers will not
> be used.
>
> Prior to version 1.11.0, builtin parameters were used by default.

The commit which removed the builtin parameters and the justification for removing it, is [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/61ec58a9bed5ec0cae60c3f3b8d46382beecc5c6).  The builtin 1024-bit key was:

```
 -----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
 MIGHAoGBALu8LcrYRnSQfEP89YDpz9vZWKP1aLQtSwju1OsPs1BMbAMCducQgAxc
 y7qokiYUxb7spWWl/fHSh6K8BJvmd4Bg6RqSp1fjBI9osHb302zI8pul34HcLKcl
 7OZicMyaUDXYzs7vnqAnSmOrHlj6/UmI0PZdFGdX2gcd8EXP4WubAgEC
 -----END DH PARAMETERS-----
```

which decodes to the following values:

```
    prime:
        00:bb:bc:2d:ca:d8:46:74:90:7c:43:fc:f5:80:e9:
        cf:db:d9:58:a3:f5:68:b4:2d:4b:08:ee:d4:eb:0f:
        b3:50:4c:6c:03:02:76:e7:10:80:0c:5c:cb:ba:a8:
        92:26:14:c5:be:ec:a5:65:a5:fd:f1:d2:87:a2:bc:
        04:9b:e6:77:80:60:e9:1a:92:a7:57:e3:04:8f:68:
        b0:76:f7:d3:6c:c8:f2:9b:a5:df:81:dc:2c:a7:25:
        ec:e6:62:70:cc:9a:50:35:d8:ce:ce:ef:9e:a0:27:
        4a:63:ab:1e:58:fa:fd:49:88:d0:f6:5d:14:67:57:
        da:07:1d:f0:45:cf:e1:6b:9b
    generator: 2 (0x2)
```

Comment: Yes, I found that. But "Prior to version 1.11.0, builtin parameters were used by default." doesn't make sense -- where are those "builtin parameters"? How big are they?

Comment: Read the source code?

Comment: @garethTheRed can you please also add that pre-1.11.0, the builtin parameters was 1024-bit and just include the actual value (`BEGIN DH PARAMETERS` line to `END DH PARAMETERS` line)? This was essentially the purpose of this question.